# Getting an x values from a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm in a sort of a predicament.

So I have a set of y data in MATLAB, and the plot comes out as a bell shaped curve. The peak goes from 0 to .25, and what I need is the duration of this peak with a threshold of .05. So basically what this means is that since this is a bell shaped curve, there are 2 instances where y = .05. I need to know what the x values are at these points and get the difference between the two, thus giving me the duration. The problem I'm having is I don't know how to get the x values. I don't have the x values, and .05 isn't an actual data point in the y vector. Is there any way I can do this, or is this impossible?

I would really appreciate any help anybody could offer, I've been stuck trying to do this for the past 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> plot(1:5, 2:6) %// example plot
>> h = get(gca,'children'); %// get a handle to the plot
>> x = get(h,'Xdata') %// get x values
x =
     1     2     3     4     5
>> y = get(h,'Ydata') %// get y values
y =
     2     3     4     5     6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the abscissae and you are creating the plot by only providing `y` as input to the plot function, i.e., `plot(y)`, then the y values are plotted against the vector `1:length(y)`.

To get the number of values above `threshold = 0.05` you can type

```
above_thresh_count = length(y(y>=threshold));
```

If the implied time step is `Ts`, then

```
(above_thresh_count - 1)*Ts
```

will give you an under-approximation (in general; unless the data set is artificial) of the duration you are seeking. If the resolution of your data is high, it is likely that it will be a good approximation. Otherwise, you could look at the interpolation commands, if you want the whole process automated and repeatedly executed. If you only care about this specific vector `y`, you could manually adjust the calculation since the `plot` command already did linear interpolation by default when invoked.

Hope that helps.